# data store with a "get or block" operation?

Tags: mongodb, redis, rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I'm looking for a data store that has a "get or block" operation. This operation would return the value associated with a key/query if that value exists or block until that value is created.

It's like a pub/sub message queue but with a memory to handle the case when the subscriber connects after the publisher has published the result.

This operation allows unrelated processes to rendezvous with each other, and it seems that it would be a very useful architectural building block to have - especially in a web environment - i.e. a web request comes in which kicks off a backend server process to do some work and the web client can get the results via a future AJAX call.

Here is an blog post I found on how to accomplish this sort of operation with mongodb:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pub-sub-with-mongodb

What other solutions are in use today? Can I do the same thing with redis or rabbitmq? I've looked at the docs for both, but it's unclear exactly how it would work. Should I roll my own server with 0MQ? Is there something out there specifically tailored for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your are correct both Redis[1] and rabbitmq[2] have pub/sub capabilities.

[1] http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

[2] http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html